# Solve probability equation

Tags: probability

Given $T$ is t-distributed with $n=7$:
$$P(T\geq -t) + P(T\geq 0)+P(T\geq t) + P(T\geq 2t) = 1.75$$

I did
$$1-P(T\leq -t) + 1-P(T\leq0) + 1-P(T\leq t) + 1-P(T\leq 2t) = 1.75$$
$$P(T\leq 2t) + 1 + 0.5 = 2.25$$
$$P(T\leq 2t) = 0.75$$
$$2t = 0.711$$ 
Thus $t=0.3555$
But the answer is t=0.711
Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer is correct. Using the symmetry of the distribution, $P(T\ge 0)=0.5$ and $P(T\ge t)=P(T\le-t)$. Hence, $P(T\ge 2t)=0.25$, $2t=0.7111$ and $t=0.3556$.

Comment: Oh! that is a relief.  This is a problem from IB and they gave the answer as 0.7111.  Maybe it is an error in the text.  Thank you.

Comment: @Sai It has to be an error in the text. I double-checked everything, the answer is $t=0.3556$. If we calculate all the probabilities, we get $0.6337+0.5+0.3663+0.25=1.75$.

Comment: It could be.  Wouldn't be the first :)